# Why does Dealer call over floor if there is 3 of a kind on the flop in live poker?

Tags: nlhe, live, dealer

I was playing live poker recently, and during one of the hands the flop came AAA (3 aces). The dealer called over the floor to watch the rest of the hand, and I was confused why this was necessary. Have you experienced this before? What is the reason for calling over the floor to watch the hand when there is 3 of the same card on the flop?

Comment: The casino probably had a bad beat jackpot. Three aces on the flop makes a jackpot likely, so the dealer wanted to protect the players' interest in this potential jackpot by having it witnessed by a floorman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This of course depends on the location. There are of course standard poker rules that are applied pretty much everywhere, but most poker rooms have various rules that apply only to them. Without knowing more details about what happened, we can only speculate/guess.

If I were to guess, I'd say that the poker room has some form of "bad beat promotions" going on. These are various prizes in money that players receive when they get a bad-beat. The rules are very specific in these cases, to ensure that such situations happen rarely. The prizes are usually collected over time from cash-rake and tournament fees.

Now, in your specific situation, 3 Aces on the flop can mean that such a bad beat is more likely to occur. Therefore the dealer might call the floor manager so that he can watch everything go down and make sure that all their specific rules for bad-beat-promotions are respected.

Again, this is entirely speculative from my part, given the small number of details you provided. But I'd be willing to bet I'm pretty close to the truth.

Comment: I'm not sure either if they had any bad-beat promotions (or any other promotions like that) going on, but this is likely the reason why

Answer (score 0):

It isn't typical to call a floor over for this. However I am guessing they had a jackpot for aces full being beat and that the players could win by having a qualifying hand with a pocket pair. So where you where playing might have a policy of calling over the floor when likely jackpot flops came down. Ask the floor why, like I said calling the floor is not typical and only someone where you where playing could give you a definitive answer. Just to clarify was this texas holdem or some pit game like three card poker?

Comment: asking would have been the smart thing to do, next time I go there i will ask!

Comment: it was 1-2 nlhe